# Idiomatic Way to Repeatedly Run Function Using Python Multiprocessing

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

Suppose I have some kind of monte carlo simulation f(x), where x is some parameter that I want to hold constant for N trials. The obvious way to parallelize this and collect the output is:

```
results = pool.map(f,x * np.ones(N))
```

However, the meaning of x in my program is really not sequence-like, so typing x * np.ones(N) seems kind of silly. None of the map variants seem to do exactly this, but maybe there exists some kind of function like:

```
results = pool.const_map(f,x)
```

Such a function could return a multiset rather than a list because the idea "repeatedly do something" does not have a notion of "order". Or maybe the developers have some interest in adding such a function? I could submit a pull request eventually when I find the time.

Comment: `apply` in a loop?

Comment: That would also work. However, map has the performance benefit of having a notion of "chunks". Does apply in a loop allow for such chunking?

Comment: You can chunk yourself, no? I'm not sure I am grokking your requirements. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Yes, I could probably do the chunking myself. My question isn't really about "requirements" per se. The multiprocessing module does allow for several ways to express things like the example I brought up, but none of them as convenient as what I mention. The purpose of my question is finding out whether I overlooked something like this already existing, and and if not seeing whether there is enough motivation to add such a thing to the library.

Comment: How about ```pool.map(f, itertools.repeat(x, N))```??

Comment: I guess that is a bit more readable equivalent to x * np.ones(N), but that doesn't really address my main question.

Comment: How would ```pool.const_map(f,x)``` behave?

Comment: What is the **main** question?

Comment: My post boils down to two main questions "does something like what I describe that I am overlooking?" and "if not do we want this?" I think the way my post gradually introduces those questions with context is a good way to pose the question, though if you and the moderators believe the question needs editing it is the usual practice of this website to do so.